# iOS APP cannot make network request suddenly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an iOS app, it connects two servers(no dependency between them), sometimes we found that the app cannot make any network request to both server, and if kill the app, start it again, everything works fine.

I did add a request queue for one server to avoid send multiple requests at the same time, but no such queue on other server. but no such issue on debug devices.

How could I find the root cause?

Comment: Can you provide a code with sending requests?